# Convert year number to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 19 columns and one of them is titled `'publish_date'`. It contains values in the format `'yyyy-mm-dd'`, however, there are some exceptions where it just shows as `'yyyy'`. For example, there is a row where the value is `2012` and I want that converted to `2012-01-01`. Is there a way to do that for all such instances?

Comment: just `pd.to_datetime(df['publish_date'])`?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['publish_date'], infer_datetime_format = True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: @elPastor thanks a lot, that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can find and replace all those cases using this:

```
df['publish_date'][df['publish_date'].str.len()==4] = df['publish_date']+'-01-01'
```

Then you need to cast it to datetime.